# How can I use pytorch pre-trained model without installing pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I only want to use pre-trained model in pytorch without installing the whole package.
Can I just copy the model module from pytorch?

Comment: @ghost2718 suggested checking ONNX, https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html - as the answer itself may get deleted for being link-only, the link is saved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do that: in order to run the model, you need not only the trained weights ('.pth.tar' file) but also the "structure" of the net: that is, the layers, how they are connected to each other etc. This network structure is coded in python and requires pytorch to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

A way of using PyTorch models without Installing PyTorch is if the model is exported in Onnx format. Once the model is in Onnx format the model can be Imported into the Onnx runtime and ca be used for Inferencing. This tutorial should help you out.[Pytorch ONNX](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html)

Comment: This may be an interesting suggestion, but right now this answer shows up in the review queue for being very short, it practically consists of a single link. As it may end up being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) in its current form, please consider extending the answer with some details, steps. For example an interesting info would be knowing if ONNX is considerably lighter to install than PyTorch.