# Using RNN Trained Model without pytorch installed

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I have trained an RNN model with pytorch. I need to use the model for prediction in an environment where I'm unable to install pytorch because of some strange dependency issue with glibc. However, I can install numpy and scipy and other libraries. So, I want to use the trained model, with the network definition, without pytorch.

I have the weights of the model as I save the model with its state dict and weights in [the standard way](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html), but I can also save it using just json/pickle files or similar.

I also have the network definition, which depends on pytorch in a number of ways. This is my RNN network definition.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import random

torch.manual_seed(1)
random.seed(1)
device = torch.device('cpu')

class RNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size,num_layers, matching_in_out=False, batch_size=1):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    self.input_size = input_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.matching_in_out = matching_in_out #length of input vector matches the length of output vector 
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size,num_layers)
    self.hidden2out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
    self.hidden = self.init_hidden()
  def forward(self, feature_list):
    feature_list=torch.tensor(feature_list)
    
    if self.matching_in_out:
      lstm_out, _ = self.lstm( feature_list.view(len( feature_list), 1, -1))
      output_space = self.hidden2out(lstm_out.view(len( feature_list), -1))
      output_scores = torch.sigmoid(output_space) #we'll need to check if we need this sigmoid
      return output_scores #output_scores
    else:
      for i in range(len(feature_list)):
        cur_ft_tensor=feature_list[i]#.view([1,1,self.input_size])
        cur_ft_tensor=cur_ft_tensor.view([1,1,self.input_size])
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(cur_ft_tensor, self.hidden)
        outs=self.hidden2out(lstm_out)
      return outs
  def init_hidden(self):
    #return torch.rand(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)
    return (torch.rand(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device),
            torch.rand(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device))
```

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880783/how-can-i-use-pytorch-pre-trained-model-without-installing-pytorch), but I'm willing to go as low level as possible. I can work with numpy array instead of tensors, and reshape instead of view, and I don't need a device setting.

Based on the class definition above, what I can see here is that I only need the following components from torch to get an output from the forward function:

- nn.LSTM
- nn.Linear
- torch.sigmoid

I think I can easily [implement the sigmoid function using numpy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-sigmoid-function-using-numpy/). However, can I have some implementation for the nn.LSTM and nn.Linear using something not involving pytorch? Also, how will I use the weights from the state dict into the new class?

So, the question is, how can I "translate" this RNN definition into a class that doesn't need pytorch, and how to use the state dict weights for it?
Alternatively, is there a "light" version of pytorch, that I can use just to run the model and yield a result?

### EDIT

I think it might be useful to include the numpy/scipy equivalent for both **nn.LSTM** and **nn.linear**. It would help us compare the numpy output to torch output for the same code, and give us some modular code/functions to use. Specifically, a numpy equivalent for the following would be great:

```
rnn = nn.LSTM(10, 20, 2)
input = torch.randn(5, 3, 10)
h0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
c0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
output, (hn, cn) = rnn(input, (h0, c0))
```

and also for linear:

```
m = nn.Linear(20, 30)
input = torch.randn(128, 20)
output = m(input)
```

Comment: Out of interest, what's the dependency issue with glibc that you're facing?

Comment: @OllieGraham On my hosting, the glibc version is 2.12, but pytorch requires 2.14 and I tried so many things to install it but I cannot (mainly because I don't have root access)

Comment: Thanks @hmghaly - I know that it doesn't answer your question, but if your hosting platform allows it I'd recommend deploying the model in a container (e.g. with Docker) so that you can configure the environment as needed and install all the relevant dependencies

Comment: Thanks @OllieGraham, but unfortunately the hosting has so many restrictions, including on installing things, on RAM, and on the number of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically implementing it in numpy and copying weights from your pytorch model can do the trick.  For your usecase you will only need to do a forward pass so we just need to implement that only

```
#Set Parameters for a small LSTM network
input_size  = 2 # size of one 'event', or sample, in our batch of data
hidden_dim  = 3 # 3 cells in the LSTM layer
output_size = 1 # desired model output

num_layers=3
torch_lstm = RNN( input_size, 
                 hidden_dim ,
                 output_size,
                 num_layers,
                 matching_in_out=True
                 )

state = torch_lstm.state_dict() # state will capture the weights of your model
```

Now for LSTM in numpy these functions will be used:
got the below code from this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-lstm-reference-card-6163ca98ae87

```
### NOT MY CODE
import numpy as np 
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid

def forget_gate(x, h, Weights_hf, Bias_hf, Weights_xf, Bias_xf, prev_cell_state):
    forget_hidden  = np.dot(Weights_hf, h) + Bias_hf
    forget_eventx  = np.dot(Weights_xf, x) + Bias_xf
    return np.multiply( sigmoid(forget_hidden + forget_eventx), prev_cell_state )

def input_gate(x, h, Weights_hi, Bias_hi, Weights_xi, Bias_xi, Weights_hl, Bias_hl, Weights_xl, Bias_xl):
    ignore_hidden  = np.dot(Weights_hi, h) + Bias_hi
    ignore_eventx  = np.dot(Weights_xi, x) + Bias_xi
    learn_hidden   = np.dot(Weights_hl, h) + Bias_hl
    learn_eventx   = np.dot(Weights_xl, x) + Bias_xl
    return np.multiply( sigmoid(ignore_eventx + ignore_hidden), np.tanh(learn_eventx + learn_hidden) )


def cell_state(forget_gate_output, input_gate_output):
    return forget_gate_output + input_gate_output

  
def output_gate(x, h, Weights_ho, Bias_ho, Weights_xo, Bias_xo, cell_state):
    out_hidden = np.dot(Weights_ho, h) + Bias_ho
    out_eventx = np.dot(Weights_xo, x) + Bias_xo
    return np.multiply( sigmoid(out_eventx + out_hidden), np.tanh(cell_state) )
```

We would need the sigmoid function as well so

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))
```

Because pytorch stores weights in stacked manner so we need to break it up for that we would need the below function

```
def get_slices(hidden_dim):
    slices=[]
    breaker=(hidden_dim*4)
    slices=[[i,i+3] for i in range(0, breaker, breaker//4)]
    return slices
```

Now we have the functions ready for lstm, now we create an lstm class to copy the weights from pytorch class and get the output from it.

```
class numpy_lstm:
    def __init__( self, layer_num=0, hidden_dim=1, matching_in_out=False):
        self.matching_in_out=matching_in_out
        self.layer_num=layer_num
        self.hidden_dim=hidden_dim
        
    def init_weights_from_pytorch(self, state):
        slices=get_slices(self.hidden_dim)
        print (slices)

        #Event (x) Weights and Biases for all gates
        
        lstm_weight_ih='lstm.weight_ih_l'+str(self.layer_num)
        self.Weights_xi = state[lstm_weight_ih][slices[0][0]:slices[0][1]].numpy()  # shape  [h, x]
        self.Weights_xf = state[lstm_weight_ih][slices[1][0]:slices[1][1]].numpy()  # shape  [h, x]
        self.Weights_xl = state[lstm_weight_ih][slices[2][0]:slices[2][1]].numpy()  # shape  [h, x]
        self.Weights_xo = state[lstm_weight_ih][slices[3][0]:slices[3][1]].numpy() # shape  [h, x]

        
        lstm_bias_ih='lstm.bias_ih_l'+str(self.layer_num)
        self.Bias_xi = state[lstm_bias_ih][slices[0][0]:slices[0][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, 1]
        self.Bias_xf = state[lstm_bias_ih][slices[1][0]:slices[1][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, 1]
        self.Bias_xl = state[lstm_bias_ih][slices[2][0]:slices[2][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, 1]
        self.Bias_xo = state[lstm_bias_ih][slices[3][0]:slices[3][1]].numpy() #shape is [h, 1]
        
        
        lstm_weight_hh='lstm.weight_hh_l'+str(self.layer_num)

        #Hidden state (h) Weights and Biases for all gates
        self.Weights_hi = state[lstm_weight_hh][slices[0][0]:slices[0][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, h]
        self.Weights_hf = state[lstm_weight_hh][slices[1][0]:slices[1][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, h]
        self.Weights_hl = state[lstm_weight_hh][slices[2][0]:slices[2][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, h]
        self.Weights_ho = state[lstm_weight_hh][slices[3][0]:slices[3][1]].numpy() #shape is [h, h]
        
        
        lstm_bias_hh='lstm.bias_hh_l'+str(self.layer_num)

        self.Bias_hi = state[lstm_bias_hh][slices[0][0]:slices[0][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, 1]
        self.Bias_hf = state[lstm_bias_hh][slices[1][0]:slices[1][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, 1]
        self.Bias_hl = state[lstm_bias_hh][slices[2][0]:slices[2][1]].numpy()  #shape is [h, 1]
        self.Bias_ho = state[lstm_bias_hh][slices[3][0]:slices[3][1]].numpy() #shape is [h, 1]
    def forward_lstm_pass(self,input_data):
        h = np.zeros(self.hidden_dim)
        c = np.zeros(self.hidden_dim)
        
        output_list=[]
        for eventx in input_data:
            f = forget_gate(eventx, h, self.Weights_hf, self.Bias_hf, self.Weights_xf, self.Bias_xf, c)
            i =  input_gate(eventx, h, self.Weights_hi, self.Bias_hi, self.Weights_xi, self.Bias_xi, 
                        self.Weights_hl, self.Bias_hl, self.Weights_xl, self.Bias_xl)
            c = cell_state(f,i)
            h = output_gate(eventx, h, self.Weights_ho, self.Bias_ho, self.Weights_xo, self.Bias_xo, c)
            if self.matching_in_out: # doesnt make sense but it was as it was in main code :(
                output_list.append(h)
        if self.matching_in_out:
            return output_list
        else:
            return h
```

Similarly for fully connected layer,

```
    
    
class fully_connected_layer:
    def __init__(self,state, dict_name='fc', ):
        self.fc_Weight = state[dict_name+'.weight'][0].numpy()
        self.fc_Bias = state[dict_name+'.bias'][0].numpy() #shape is [,output_size]
        
    def forward(self,lstm_output, is_sigmoid=True):
        res=np.dot(self.fc_Weight, lstm_output)+self.fc_Bias
        print (res)
        if is_sigmoid:
            return sigmoid(res)
        else:
            return res
```

Now we would need one class to call all of them together and generalise them with respect to multiple layers
You can modify the below class if you need more Fully connected layers or want to set false condition for sigmoid etc.

```
        
class RNN_model_Numpy:
    def __init__(self, state, input_size, hidden_dim, output_size, num_layers, matching_in_out=True):
        self.lstm_layers=[]
        for i in range(0, num_layers):
            lstm_layer_obj=numpy_lstm(layer_num=i, hidden_dim=hidden_dim, matching_in_out=True)
            lstm_layer_obj.init_weights_from_pytorch(state) 
            self.lstm_layers.append(lstm_layer_obj)
        
        self.hidden2out=fully_connected_layer(state, dict_name='hidden2out')
        
    def forward(self, feature_list):
        for x in self.lstm_layers:
            lstm_output=x.forward_lstm_pass(feature_list)
            feature_list=lstm_output
            
        return self.hidden2out.forward(feature_list, is_sigmoid=False)
```

Sanity check on a numpy variable:

```
data = np.array(
           [[1,1],
            [2,2],
            [3,3]])



check=RNN_model_Numpy(state, input_size, hidden_dim, output_size, num_layers)
check.forward(data)
```

EXPLANATION:
Since we just need forward pass, we would need certain functions that are required in LSTM, for that we have the forget gate, input gate, cell gate and output gate. They are just some operations that are done on the input that you give.

For get_slices function, this is used to break down the weight matrix that we get from pytorch state dictionary (state dictionary) is the dictionary which contains the weights of all the layers that we have in our network.
For LSTM particularly have it in this order  ignore, forget, learn, output. So for that we would need to break it up for different LSTM cells.

For numpy_lstm class, we have init_weights_from_pytorch function which must be called, what it will do is that it will extract the weights from state dictionary which we got earlier from pytorch model object and then populate the numpy array weights with the pytorch weights. You can first train your model and then save the state dictionary through pickle and then use it.

The fully connected layer class just implements the hidden2out neural network.

Finally our rnn_model_numpy class is there to ensure that if you have multiple layers then it is able to send the output of one layer of lstm to other layer of lstm.

Lastly there is a small sanity check on data variable.

IMPORTANT NOTE: PLEASE NOTE THAT YOU MIGHT GET DIMENSION ERROR AS PYTORCH WAY OF HANDLING INPUT IS COMPLETELY DIFFERENT SO PLEASE ENSURE THAT YOU INPUT NUMPY IS OF SIMILAR SHAPE AS DATA VARIABLE.

Important references:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html

https://christinakouridi.blog/2019/06/19/backpropagation-lstm/

Comment: This is quite useful, thank you. But there are some points in the code that I'm unable to reuse easily. Would it be possible if you can provide the code that is equivalent to:
rnn = nn.LSTM(10, 20, 2)
input = torch.randn(5, 3, 10)
h0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
c0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
output, (hn, cn) = rnn(input, (h0, c0))
and the code that is equivalent to:
m = nn.Linear(20, 30)
input = torch.randn(128, 20)
output = m(input)

So that we can compare the output of the numpy equivalent to pytorch, and also to have modular equivalent to LSTM and linear, thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't show clearly in the comment above, I included an update at the end of the question, I would appreciate it if you can help with that

Comment: The solution is made with respect to the pytorch weights. So all you need to do is simply define input size, output size etc and create the RNN class that you showed in your question, that will have the Linear Neural network layer as well. Then you need to call the numpy and give the state dictionary as i did in the end and give the input of the shape. My code just copies the weights of the pytorch and based on the number of weights it can easily get to know the shape of neural network

Answer (score 4):

You should try to export the model using [torch.onnx](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html). The page gives you an example that you can start with.

An alternative is to use [TorchScript](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html), but that requires torch libraries.

Both of these can be run without python. You can load torchscript in a C++ application https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html

ONNX is much more portable and you can use in languages such as C#, Java, or Javascript
https://onnxruntime.ai/ (even on the browser)

#### A running example

Just modifying a little your example to go over the errors I found

Notice that via tracing any if/elif/else, for, while will be unrolled

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import random

torch.manual_seed(1)
random.seed(1)
device = torch.device('cpu')

class RNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size,num_layers, matching_in_out=False, batch_size=1):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    self.input_size = input_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.matching_in_out = matching_in_out #length of input vector matches the length of output vector 
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size,num_layers)
    self.hidden2out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
  def forward(self, x, h0, c0):
    lstm_out, (hidden_a, hidden_b) = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
    outs=self.hidden2out(lstm_out)
    return outs, (hidden_a, hidden_b)
  def init_hidden(self):
    #return torch.rand(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)
    return (torch.rand(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device).detach(),
            torch.rand(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device).detach())

# convert the arguments passed during onnx.export call
class MWrapper(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(MWrapper, self).__init__()
        self.model = model;
    def forward(self, kwargs):
        return self.model(**kwargs)
```

Run an example

```py
rnn = RNN(10, 10, 10, 3)
X = torch.randn(3,1,10)
h0,c0  = rnn.init_hidden()
print(rnn(X, h0, c0)[0])
```

Use the same input to trace the model and export an onnx file

```py
torch.onnx.export(MWrapper(rnn), {'x':X,'h0':h0,'c0':c0}, 'rnn.onnx', 
                  dynamic_axes={'x':{1:'N'},
                               'c0':{1: 'N'},
                               'h0':{1: 'N'}
                               },
                  input_names=['x', 'h0', 'c0'],
                  output_names=['y', 'hn', 'cn']
                 )
```

Notice that you can use symbolic values for the dimensions of some axes of some inputs. Unspecified dimensions will be fixed with the values from the traced inputs. By default [LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) uses dimension 1 as batch.

Next we load the ONNX model and pass the same inputs

```py
import onnxruntime
ort_model = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('rnn.onnx')
print(ort_model.run(['y'], {'x':X.numpy(), 'c0':c0.numpy(), 'h0':h0.numpy()}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems promising but for some reason it's very slow, I've been loading the model in the example for perhaps 10 minutes and it got killed eventually. Maybe it's because the model in the example was quite big, I'll just need to figure out how to try it with my smaller model

Comment: Exporting your torch model into ONNX is also what I would do if I didn't have access to pytorch. Usually an ONNX model is faster than the Pytorch model, you still might face issues during the export process. If the inference time is a big concern and you have a nvidia gpu, you could try to use TensorRT